# flutter http.get request does not work anymore

Tags: flutter, flutter-http

until some days ago everything was working fine. I am not able to remember any changes in the code or in the model.

In a flutter app I do not have any response from a http.get request and I just see "Errors" in my app screen.

I have developed also the api server so I see the get request with rc 200
Trying the same request from a curl it works and return 200

From the console also if I launch the app with flutter run -v I do not see any error, only the print before the final response.

Any idea how can I debug it?

Thanks

Comment: Try adding a try catch statement, or using the debug tools from vscode or android studio, You said that you have error on your screen, so you could add some print on the flow and then share it here to help you

Comment: I do not know what happened, I tried to debug running on a different device and from the console I saw the right response.body json, after a while it started to work again. Thanks in any case, sorry.